# Kalman Filter tracking in the presence of Occlusion

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tracking, video-processing

I have tried using the Kalman filter for prediction, and it works perfectly. However, in the presence of occlusion, the code does not predict correctly at all.
Here is the code I've written:

```
import cv


class Target:

    def __init__(self): 
        self.capture = cv.CaptureFromFile('F:\\Project\\Video3\\av.avi') 
        cv.NamedWindow("Target", 1)


    def run(self):
        frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
        frame_size = cv.GetSize(frame)
        fps=cv.GetCaptureProperty(self.capture, cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS)

        color_image = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), 8, 3)
        grey_image = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
        moving_average = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3)

        # Create Kalman Filter
        kalman = cv.CreateKalman(4, 2, 0)
        kalman_state = cv.CreateMat(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC1)
        kalman_process_noise = cv.CreateMat(4, 1, cv.CV_32FC1)
        kalman_measurement = cv.CreateMat(2, 1, cv.CV_32FC1)

        first = True
        second=True
        n=0
        cp11 = []
        cp22 = []
        center_point1 = []
        predict_pt1 = []
        count=0

        while True:
            closest_to_left = cv.GetSize(frame)[0]
            closest_to_right = cv.GetSize(frame)[1]

            color_image = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)

            cv.Smooth(color_image, color_image, cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 0)
            if first:
                difference = cv.CloneImage(color_image) #fully copies the image.
                temp = cv.CloneImage(color_image)
                cv.ConvertScale(color_image, moving_average, 1.0, 0.0) 
                first = False 
            else:          
                cv.RunningAvg(color_image, moving_average, 0.02, None) 

            cv.ConvertScale(moving_average, temp, 1.0, 0.0)

            # Minus the current frame from the moving average.
            cv.AbsDiff(color_image, temp, difference) 

            # Convert the image to grayscale.
            cv.CvtColor(difference, grey_image, cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)

            # Convert the image to black and white.
            cv.Threshold(grey_image, grey_image, 70, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)

            # Dilate and erode to get people blobs
            cv.Dilate(grey_image, grey_image, None, 18)  
            cv.Erode(grey_image, grey_image, None, 10) 

            storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0) 
            contour = cv.FindContours(grey_image, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

            points = []

            i=0
            k=0
            while contour:
                area=cv.ContourArea(list(contour))
                #print area
                bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(list(contour))
                contour = contour.h_next() 
                if (area > 1500.0):
                    pt1 = (bound_rect[0], bound_rect[1])
                    pt2 = (bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2], bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3])
                    points.append(pt1)
                    points.append(pt2)
                    cv.Rectangle(color_image, pt1, pt2, cv.CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1)

                    cp1 = bound_rect[0] + (bound_rect[2]/2)
                    cp2 = bound_rect[1] + (bound_rect[3]/2)
                    cp11.append(cp1)
                    cp22.append(cp2)

                    # set previous state for prediction
                    kalman.state_pre[0,0]  = cp1
                    kalman.state_pre[1,0]  = cp2
                    kalman.state_pre[2,0]  = 0
                    kalman.state_pre[3,0]  = 0

                    # set kalman transition matrix
                    kalman.transition_matrix[0,0] = 1
                    kalman.transition_matrix[0,1] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[0,2] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[0,3] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[1,0] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[1,1] = 1
                    kalman.transition_matrix[1,2] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[1,3] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[2,0] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[2,1] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[2,2] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[2,3] = 1
                    kalman.transition_matrix[3,0] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[3,1] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[3,2] = 0
                    kalman.transition_matrix[3,3] = 1

                    # set Kalman Filter
                    cv.SetIdentity(kalman.measurement_matrix, cv.RealScalar(1))
                    cv.SetIdentity(kalman.process_noise_cov, cv.RealScalar(1e-5))
                    cv.SetIdentity(kalman.measurement_noise_cov, cv.RealScalar(1e-1))
                    cv.SetIdentity(kalman.error_cov_post, cv.RealScalar(1))

                    #Prediction
                    kalman_prediction = cv.KalmanPredict(kalman)
                    predict_pt  = (int(kalman_prediction[0,0]),int( kalman_prediction[1,0]))
                    predict_pt1.append(predict_pt)
                    print "Prediction",predict_pt
                    #Correction
                    kalman_estimated = cv.KalmanCorrect(kalman, kalman_measurement)
                    state_pt = (kalman_estimated[0,0], kalman_estimated[1,0])

                    #measurement
                    kalman_measurement[0, 0] = center_point[0]
                    kalman_measurement[1, 0] = center_point[1]

            while(i<count):
                cv.Circle(color_image, (cp11[i], cp22[i]), 1, cv.CV_RGB(255, 100, 0), 1)


                cv.Circle(color_image, predict_pt1[i], 1, cv.CV_RGB(0, 255, 0), 1)
                i=i+1
            cv.ShowImage("Target", color_image)

            c = cv.WaitKey(int(fps))  
            if c == 27: 
                break

if __name__=="__main__":
    t = Target()
    t.run()
```

Comment: Any reason why you are using the old `cv` interface instead of the newer `cv2`? As for the actual question, it would help if you could illustrate your problem in some way. "Not working in presence of occlusion" is quite vague.

Comment: I agree with the comment above. Also, uploading some images would help us understand the problem.

Comment: I saw an example of tracking which used cv and since I started learning with cv, I've continued using it. I started tracking a man who was walking in a room. When he goes behind a screen, the prediction and the tracking points do not appear. The tracking points should not appear, so that is okay. But from what I've read about Kalman Filters, it should continue to predict even when the man is behind the screen. But the above code does not do that.

Answer (score 0):

The Kalman filter continually updates the predicted value with information from the actual measurement. During times of occlusion you would have to just use the Kalman prediction value and somehow exclude measurement information. i.e. . All the state vector components are predicted according to the last velocity estimate.

This is an example:

http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/15/65/55/PDF/Girondel_SSIAI_2004.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You have to detect that the object is occluded, then don't use the measurement step, just the prediction step.

What this means is that if an occlusion occurs, your measurement is completely wrong, so the measurement step does not give you any  new information on where the object is. You can express this as giving your observation a really large covariance matrix, or (this being essentially the same) you can just ignore the observation. Either way, because time doesn't stop, you should keep updating the prediction of your state. The covariance of the state should get large because no  new information is added.